# Maximo Anywhere View child workorders and their related objects in WorkExecution App

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

I want to extend the WorkExecution App for IBM Maximo Anywhere to show the children of a workorder and their specifications

Thus the preceived structure should be

```
WORKORDER
    |___CHILD WORKORDER
    |       |____ASSET
    |       |____WORKORDERSPEC
    |       |____etc...
    |___TASKS
    |___MATERIAL
    |___LABOR
    |___WORKORDERSPEC
    |___etc...
```

I managed to add the basic child workorder info, but I'm stuck on adding the WORKORDERSPEC for the child workorders

I've followed the basic example on the IBM website:
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSPJLC_7.6.1/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc_7.6.1/config_apps/t_add_rel_records.html

For this I created a new View on WORKORDER (WOCHILDREN) and added that object to the objectstructure OSLCWODETAIL.
That changed the OSLC Resource 'workOrder' accordingly. This worked for displaying basic (or direct) CHILD WORKORDER info.

Then I added the WORKORDERSPEC object again under the WOCHILDREN object in the objectstructure OSLCWODETAIL. So the
hierarchy looks like: WORKORDER/WOCHILDREN/WORKORDERSPEC
That changed the OSLC Resource 'workOrder', but for the the original WORKORDER/WORKORDERSPEC their are two OSLC Resource Mappings (CLASSPECID and ASSETATTRID)

I don't know why, but I can't configure them for the WORKORDERSPEC under WOCHILDREN. Without it the build fails for the missing attribute assetattr and classspec.
Any ideas why this is? Or how to solve it?

Is this the correct strategy for my problem? I also considered a different approuch by duplicating the OSLCWODETAIL object structure and create a new OSLC Resource for it.
Then I only have to couple them in the app like so:

```
WORKORDER
    |___WORKORDER(duplicate)
    |       |___WORKORDERSPEC
    |       |___MATERIAL
    |       |___LABOR
    |       |___TASKS
    |       |___etc...
    |___WORKORDERSPEC
    |___MATERIAL
    |___LABOR
    |___TASKS
    |___etc...
```

But I have no idea how to do that in Maximo Anywhere app.xml

I hope you have some suggestions on how to connect these things together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My strategy is not to build the structure to the 3rd level, instead, you create a relationship in WORKORDER to SPEC for all child wo's, add CHILDWOSPEC under the OSLCWODETAIL object structure.

Then after getting the CHILDWOSPEC resource to Anywhere, you use filter function in your custom handler to filter the Spec information only for that particular child wo.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Hi Andy, I have to more specific. I actually want to have more functionality on the child WO. Like reporting materials and things like that. Some of those need to be on the main and child wo's. The strategy your suggesting might work, but it is not very nice.

Comment: After some additional research, I've found that the API does support self-referencing objects. But, not sure how to make these load properly. Perhaps the logic for assetancestor and locancestor has some clues.

Comment: hi Andy, I like to learn more about your solution. Can you make it more specific? (for example use tasks)